# Worker DOM not creating a amp-iframe with attributes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, amp-html

I'm facing some issues with amp and worker DOM, cause I've been trying to create a amp element with a external javascript code and always got the same problem, [amp-script] Sanitized node, if a try to create another element works.

this code:

```
const container = document.getElementById('audimaWidget');
let iframe = `<amp-iframe
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
height=150
layout="responsive" 
width=320
scrolling="no" 
frameborder="0" 
src="http://localhost/api/player?audioUrl=http://localhost/audios/oglobo.mp3&skin=default&hasBanner=false&hasAdsAudio=false">
    <amp-img src="http://localhost/img/player.png" layout="fill" placeholder />
</amp-iframe>
`;

container.innerHTML = iframe;
```

was supposed to rendering a element called amp-iframe with the above attrs, but it doesn't works.
I've tried to create another element, like a div, even a amp-img with the same attrs, work fine, but when I try to create a amp iframe, I got nothing, just this console.log :
[image: errors that a got when a try to create a amp-iframe]

Anyone can help me with this? I'm using amp boilerplate, here is my code :

[image: amp.article.html]

[image: audio-player.js]

Comment: It isn't very useful to post pictures of code, since it is hard to read, and we can't copy this into our console to test it. Please copy and paste your actual code text instead, wrapped in ``` tags to format it as code.